# Powershell Start-Process with variable FilePath

Tags: powershell

Hi I need to run a variable process as elevated using powershell.
The following code don't work because for some reason Powershell don't expand the variable:

```
$exe = "C:\$var.exe"
Start-Process $exe -Verb runas
```

But I get this error

> Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified
>
> +Start-Process $exe -Verb runas;

Comment: If you output `$var` and `$exe` before running `Start-Process` do they have the expected values?

Comment: @Vittorio Vaselli Some code is missing, just paste all the code related to the different variables otherwise it's not understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$var`-variable expanded when you declared `$exe`-string as long as you use double-quotes like you have in the question. Single quotes however `$exe = 'c:\$var.exe'` would not work as single quotes makes a literal string.

Output `$exe` to verify the path. Your `$var` value is probably wrong.

The error just says which line it ran, not which path it actually used except for that it's stored in the `$exe`-variable.

```
$var = "nonexistingfile"
$exe = "c:\$var.exe"
$exe
c:\nonexistingfile.exe

Start-Process $exe
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process $exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

However with a valid path:

```
$var = "windows\system32\notepad"
$exe = "c:\$var.exe"
$exe
c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe

Start-Process $exe
#Starts notepad
```

Answer (score -1):

I like to combine strings using arrays and `-join`:

```
$exe = 'C:\',$var,'.exe' -join ''
```

next I would test if the executable exists and run it or write an error

```
if(Test-Path -LiteralPath $exe) {
    Start-Process $exe -Verb runas
} else {
    Write-Error "the executable could not be found"
}
```